# Can anyone tell me the difference between FrameworkElement obj=sender as FrameworkElement and FrameworkElement obj=(FrameworkElement) someobject

Tags: c#, silverlight, frameworkelement

I am new to programming in Silverlight. Can anyone tell me the difference between

```
FrameworkElement obj=sender as FrameworkElement
```

and

```
FrameworkElement obj=(FrameworkElement)someobject
```

Comment: You should retag your question for the c# types or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FrameworkElement obj=sender as FrameworkElement
```

after this code obj will be FrameworkElement, if type of it is FrameworkElement, or null, in other cases. This code will not throw **InvalidCastException**.

```
FrameworkElement obj=(FrameworkElement)sender
```

this is explicit conversion, and this operation can throw an **InvalidCastException**

[Casting and Type Conversions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the difference is

`FrameworkElement obj=sender as FrameworkElement` always works. If sender is not of type FrameworkElement, obj is null, otherwise you will find the casted object in there.

`FrameworkElement obj=(FrameworkElement)someobject` produces an InvalidCastException if sender cannot be casted to type FrameworkElement.